# Can I get OneDrive to automatically convert all documents

Tags: onedrive

I have uploaded a whole load of word docs to OneDrive.  I want to be able to work with and edit these files.  They are older, so Word for iPad insists on converting and saving before allowing me to edit.  However it saves them to the root of the drive rather than in place so my filing is off.

Can I somehow do a bulk convert on all my documents and leave them in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any built in way, but I have a tool - [DocTo](https://github.com/tobya/DocTo/releases) that converts word documents to other formats.

If you have Word 2010 or later installed, you can use the following commandline with the docto tool to convert all files in a folder on your disk, then once converted upload them to onedrive.

```
"docto.exe"  -f "c:\mydocs\"  -o "C:\GeneratedFiles\"    -T  wdFormatDocumentDefault 
             -C 16 -OX .docx -X false
```

The converted files dont need to be resaved by word online.